# this is my code and i want to know how to make the picture automatically boreder every phone

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i want the height and width to adjust with each phone so the picture will fit right in every phone.
i am just writing more so the post would get submitted the qustion is simple

```
// 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: (AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('lord thunder'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
        )),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Image.asset('images/images.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
``

i was trying to make the picture fit the body perfectly on each phone.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BoxFit.cover` propertry inside `DecorationImage`

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("images/images.jpg"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover
    )
  ),
),
```